# how can I check if user insert more than one word , space or special char?

Tags: java, android, string, authentication

[image: In this interface how to make user insert only one word without space]

in this interface how to make user insert only one word without space or special symbol so How Can I do it?

Comment: What framework are you using? Have you built the rest of the UI already?

Comment: Do you want to handle the removal of white spaces and special characters or you just want to restrict the user from entering white spaces and special characters ?

Comment: I want to restrict the user from entering white spaces and special characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the following setup

layout.xml

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

}

TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String text=editText.getText().toString();
        String[] words=text.split("\\s+");
        if(words.length>1){
            editText.setError("Please donot enter more than a word!");
            editText.setText(words[0]);
        }
        else{
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-z0-9 ]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
            boolean b = m.find();

            if (b) {
                editText.setError("Please donot enter any special character!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Character.isWhitespace`

something like this:

```
public static boolean containSpace(final String userName){
    if(userName != null){
        for(int i = 0; i < userName.length(); i++){
            if(Character.isWhitespace(userName.charAt(i))){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Assuming you only want to allow letters and numbers, this expression would do:

```java
"[a-zA-Z0-9]+"

// same as above
"\\p{Alnum}+"

// full unicode support, e.g. accented letters like é, ô, and ñ
"(?U)\\p{Alnum}+"
```

Code to check this is:

```java
if (value.matches("(?U)\\p{Alnum}+")) {
    // value is good
} else {
    // value is bad
}
```